# Asp.net From dictionary to const

Tags: c#, dictionary, constants

I have simple `Dictionary<string, string>` which contains more than 1400 items. All  I need is just generate new .cs file with >1400 constants like `public const string KEY = Value` (from my dictionary). How can I do that?

Comment: Maybe i should use T4 templates?

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use linq `select` write `public const string {key}= {value}` values.

then use `File.AppendAllLines` to write the file.

```
Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dict.Add("key1", "value1");
dict.Add("key2", "value2");
var result = dict.Select(x => $"public const string {x.Key} = {x.Value}");
File.AppendAllLines("<your file path>", result)
```